# Code crashes on Mac OSX, not linux?

Tags: tables, listings

Using TexWorks.  2 people using Mac OSX, one El Capitan, one Yosemite.
1 person using linux.

The following code works on linux:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|} \hline
Scalar form &       Meaning &       Element-by-element for vectors x and y  \\ \hline
\mati{2 + 3}    &       add             &       \mati{x .+ y}       \\ \hline
\end{lstlistings}
```

both Mac OSX fail on this code.  Is it a bug, or something wrong?
version on Linux is: pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
version on Mac OSX: pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015)

Full mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}

\parindent0pt  \parskip10pt     % make block paragraphs
\raggedright                                % do not right justify
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[top=0.5in, bottom=1in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=DeepPink4,linkcolor=DarkRed, urlcolor=DarkBlue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{longtable}

\title{test}
\author{foo}
\date{\today}   

\lstset{ 
      backgroundcolor=\color{lgray},  
%   basicstyle=\footnotesize \ttfamily \color{black} \bfseries,   
      breakatwhitespace=false,       
      breaklines=true,               
      captionpos=b,                   
      commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},   
      deletekeywords={...},          
      escapeinside={\%*}{*)},                  
      frame=single,                  
      keywordstyle=\textbf,  
      morekeywords={BRIEFDescriptorConfig,string,TiXmlNode,DetectorDescriptorConfigContainer,istringstream,cerr,exit}, 
      identifierstyle=\color{black},
      stringstyle=\color{blue},      
      language=Java,                
      numbers=right,                 
      numbersep=5pt,                  
      numberstyle=\tiny\color{black}, 
      rulecolor=\color{black},        
      showspaces=false,               
      showstringspaces=false,        
      showtabs=false,                
      stepnumber=1,                   
      tabsize=5,                     
      title=\lstname,                 
}

\newcommand{\matlab}{\begin{lstlisting}[language=matlab]}
\newcommand\mati[1]{{\lstinline[language=matlab]{#1}}}
\raggedbottom

\title{\bf Test Title}
\begin{document}                   % End of preamble, start of text.
\frontmatter                            % only in book class (roman page #s)
\maketitle                                  % Print title page.
\pagebreak
credits go here
\pagebreak
\tableofcontents                        % Print table of contents
\newpage
\mainmatter                                 % only in book class (arabic page #s)
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|} \hline
Scalar form &       Meaning &       Element-by-element for vectors x and y  \\ \hline
\mati{2 + 3}    &       add             &       \mati{x .+ y}       \\ \hline
\mati{2 - 3}    &       subtract    &       \mati{x .- y}       \\ \hline
\mati{2 * 3}    &       multiply        &       \mati{x .* y}       \\ \hline
\mati{2 / 3}        &       divide          &       \mati{x ./ y}       \\ \hline
\mati{2 ^ 3}    &       exponentiation  &       \mati{x .^ y}       \\ \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: No failure, for me.

Comment: @Dov do you get an error message on OSX? What does the log file contain?

Comment: Could you show the full log file from the failure, in a code section in the question

Comment: I've typeset the given example on both TeX Live 2015 (updated to the frozen state) and TeX Live 2016 with all updates and had no problem. I would guess that the Macs probably have some items in their personal tree that might be interfering with the compile. Please supply a log file from one of the failed runs.

Comment: Will ask them to post...